# Разбор слова "доброта"

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, какой состав слова *доброта*?

Answer (score 2):

ДОБРОТА: корень [добр] + суффикс [от] + окончание [а].

Суффикс *-от-*  образует имена существительные со значением:
отвлеченного признака: быстр/от/а, прям/от/а, долг/от/а, прост/от/а, глух/от/а, слеп/от/а;
совокупности лиц: бедн/от/а, пех/от/а.

[ИСТОЧНИК](http://www.slovorod.ru/russian-suffixes.html)